# How can Wordpress user edit Organisation details?

Tags: wordpress

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I can't find a solution...

I've created a custom Profile for an Individual's contact details and one for their Organisation's contact details. I've added shortcodes for both of these to separate pages in Wordpress. The user that I'm logged in with has an associated Individual contact record in CiviCRM and that Individial is an Employee of an Organization. I've also made sure the Individiual has access rights to edit the Organization contact details. This relationship was initially created via a Contribution page using profiles to both capture the users personal details and organization details using the 'on behalf of profile'. All good in that a logged in user can edit their Individual contact details, but when I try and access the page in Wordpress where the shortcode is for the Organization profile I get message:

```
This profile is configured for contact type 'Organization'. It cannot be used to edit contacts of other types.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can an individual edit his organisation's details?

Answer (score 1):

there is another option you might not know about. Users can be given access to their "My Contact Dashboard" eg at civicrm/user?reset=1 (in Drupal it is at that path).

And if X has permissioned relationship over Y, and if you have not unset it from /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 then X should see Y listed, and should be able to 'edit' (some of) their details. hth

Comment: Thanks Peter, but issue I have with that is that I can't embed the result of clicking edit next to organisation listed in an existing Wordpress page, or get the result in a page to start with without clicking the link. Sadly the whole process of working with CiviCRM data in WP is turning out to be very messy. Hope this all gets addressed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a different shortcode. (At least in CiviCRM 4.7.22)

1. Make sure that in the employee's Contact > Relationships tab that by Permissions it is checked that the Employee can View and Edit the Employer Contact.
2. When the Employee logs into their dashboard, scroll all the way to the bottom and you will see a Relationship section showing "employee" as Employee of "Employer". Over to the right you will see Edit Contact Information & Dashboard. This will allow you to access the "Employer" Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Carl. So if this is right, then i was pointing in the right direction but don't know enough WP to be able to help him with his comment